# Alternative 'change' event

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am using 'change' event to import a file from a browser to a frontEnd. I mean, in order to know when the file is selected with the file browser, I am waiting for the 'change' event in my JavaScript code.

```
 /**
* Select a file to import
*  
*  - fn: callback function
**/
function selectFileToImport(fn) {
    var objFile = document.createElement('input');
    objFile.setAttribute('type', 'file');

    objFile.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var archivos=e.target.files;
        var archivo=archivos[0];            
         fn(archivo);            
        }, false);

    objFile.click();
}
```

My problem is that not always the event change is triggered, so sometimes after click on accept in the browser dialog I get no results, the selected file field is empty. It is not related with select the same file(I know that 'change' method is triggered only when the field really change). I have tried 'input'event out but it does not work. Could anybody give me an alternative?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an example for you with Jquery :

Script :

```
$("document").ready(function(){  
$("#upload").change(function() {
            alert('New File Uploaded!!! the file name is : ' + this.files[0].name );
        });
});
```

HTML :

```
<input type="file" id="upload">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/NbGBj/2345/

Comment: I am using a technology that does not use JQuery, but thank you for your answer and your example.